# Why is "by" on a vector not from a data.table column very slow?

Tags: r, data.table

```
test <- data.table(x=sample.int(10, 1000000, replace=TRUE))
y <- test$x
test[,.N, by=x] # fast
test[,.N, by=y] # extremely slow
```

Why it is slow on the second case?

It is even faster to do this:

```
test[,y:=y]
test[,.N, by=y]
test[,y:=NULL]
```

It looks as if it is poorly optimized?

Comment: Why should `data.table` be able to optimize things that you store in arbitrary locations in memory?

Comment: Thanks for the report. For now, you can do: `test[, .N, by=list(y)]` or `test[, .N, by="y"]`. I'll try to find and fix the issue. Would be great if you can file a bug report [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?atid=975&group_id=240&func=browse)

Comment: @Arun *why should it* be fast this way? This doesn't seem like the its use was intended?

Comment: I think some people have become too enamored by `data.table` to see its flaws ;)

Comment: @eddi if there is a simple enough fix its a simple question. I would have *thought* along the lines of Ari. If not why not? How can data.table be as fast grouping on R level objects?

Comment: @SimonO101 I don't really know why you think that "R level objects" and columns of a `data.table` are very different from each other - the main difference between those two is that they live in different environments.

Comment: @SimonO101, because we can :). Why shouldn't it be? It's just that the lazy evaluation doesn't seem to work with `by=y` because it's not read in as a character (by="y") or as a call (by=list(y)) and therefore the value of y gets substituted to "by", which runs another part of the code which was designed for quoted expressions.

Comment: I confess that I had the same reaction as Ari and Simon, possibly because my intuition is that grouping on non-data.table columns feels to me like a code pattern that I would actively discourage as confusing. (Maybe it's an explicit/implicit thing...)

Comment: @joran, AFAIK the requirement is that the length of "by" should match the number of rows. This enables one to group on-the-fly by doing something like: `DT <- data.table(x=c(1,1,2,2,3), y=1:5); DT[, sum(y), by=x%%2]` (strictly speaking, x%%2 does not exist in DT).

Comment: @Arun well these revelations just make me *more* enamoured with `data.table` ;)

Comment: @Arun That example seems very different to me. I'm just saying that if my _entire_ `by` expression references only things not contained in my data table, I wouldn't expect that to work, especially reading the documentation.

Comment: @colinfang, the "y" is internally converted to `list(y)`. The only case which seemed to have slipped through the cracks (so far) is `by=y` and y is not a quoted expression/call/symbol.

Comment: @joran, the documentation currently mentions just "column names", you're right. Will add a note somewhere to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I forgot to update this post.

#### This was fixed long back in commit #1039 of v1.8.11. From [**NEWS**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=datatable&revision=1039):

> Fixed `#5106` where `DT[, .N, by=y]` where `y` is a vector with `length(y) = nrow(DT)`, but `y` is not a column in `DT`. Thanks to `colinfang` for reporting.

#### Testing on v1.8.11 commit 1187:

```
require(data.table)
test <- data.table(x=sample.int(10, 1000000, replace=TRUE))
y <- test$x

system.time(ans1 <- test[,.N, by=x])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.015   0.000   0.016 

system.time(ans2 <- test[,.N, by=y])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.015   0.000   0.015 

setnames(ans2, "y", "x")
identical(ans1, ans2) # [1] TRUE
```